# run time error in android devices

Tags: java, android

i have created an app and when i was checking it with my device it shows the following error

[2011-02-22 11:30:37 - Chapter05] Failed to upload Chapter.apk on device 'HT96WKF01291'
[2011-02-22 11:30:37 - Chapter05] java.io.IOException: Unable to open sync connection!
[2011-02-22 11:30:37 - Chapter05] Launch canceled!

What it refers, pls help me in solving this issue

Comment: Have you set the USB debugging option to true? Under what mode is your device connected to the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try killing the **Android Debug Bridge (adb)** by just running the command `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` on your command prompt.

Also try disbale/enable the `USB Debugging` option on your device

Note: If you have not added the `android-sdk-windows\platform-tools` or `android-sdk-windows\tools` directory to the windows path in your `system environments` then you can not able to run this command directly. Therefore you need to go this path and after that run the above mentioned command.

Answer (score 1):

When you are opening the app you are sync connection, but which is not possible for your device. So it is throwing a IOException.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall previously build apk if any. restart your eclipse and restart you device and try again